# Multi sim card slots Mobile WIFI Router

Tags: wifi, networking, router

I've been searching for a Mobile WIFI Router that supports 4 sim card slots but with no result, have anyone of you stumbled upon such a thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PepWave MAX HD4](https://www.peplink.com/products/max-cellular-router/multi-cellular/#hd4) would be the item you are looking for.